# Duplicate characters when typing in VS 2022 .cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

[image: I am typing only once a character but it automatic creates its duplicate.]

In .cs or .vb code area whenever i type something it gets double.

example a will be aa if will be iiff

Even if I type enter it will add two lines instead of one and backspace and other keys are working in same manner.

When I am typing in .aspx page or anywhere else my keyboard works fine.

I tried few things to solve this like:

1. code clean up, build, rebuild
2. restart visual studio and pc

But still facing the same.

Comment: Do you have an .editorconfig  file somewhere on your project root folder?

Comment: No, Idon't have.

Comment: Try starting Visual Studio in [safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022), if this stops the problem there may be a Visual Studio extension causing the problem. To start in safemode, from the windows start menu, traverse to VS2022, select developer prompt and enter devenv /safemode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a repair on vs. This issue has cropped up over the years - even with previous versions. So, repair your install.

you can go tools->get tools and features.

You then get this:

[image]

Close above screen, and then you see this:

[image]

And from above, choose this:

[image]

so, usually a repair should fix this issue.

I suppose it possible you are remoting into the computer - and that could be a issue, but I suggest the above as a first step here.

## Edit: Try this if the issue is ONLY for HTML editing

Go to settings, from Setting select Options, from Options select Text Editor, from Text Editor Select HTML, from HTML Select General, from General Disable Auto List Members. A change of this setting has been confirmed to be a fix.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work :(

Comment: Hum, as noted, the solution works for some. Perhaps more details as to your setup, but it's hard to guess here. You could say try vs2019, and say try the x32 bit version, and see if that works any better. It may well be keyboard or language settings.

Comment: The strange thing is it only opens on cshtml files, and only under the line 89!

Comment: Just ran into exactly the same thing... was working fine - then whilst typing suddenly on a single file line 89 onwards double typing WTF?!

Comment: This did not work for me. Consider giving a look to the answer provided by Paul H, as [this is a known defect](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/double-characters-when-typing-html-tags-in-cshtml/1637052).

Comment: Thank you! Based on that link, I have added a edit to my post.

Comment: I think I solved the keystrokes duplication problem, when I was not even trying to fix it. I can't know if it was really the solution, but I don't want to get back to the old situation. It seems if I go to WinMerge change the file encoding from "01252 - Western European (Windows)" to "65001 - Unicode (UTF-8)", with BOM, problem becomes solved. After this change, I had to fix some French spelling where there were accents.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: The second (Edit) answer worked for me (VS 2022). The first one didn't work.

Comment: I had this problem for css and less files.  Repair did not work.  Unchecking Auto List members did work.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue in a .cshtml file. I discovered that I was trying to add a jquery event underneath a method that contained an @ symbol (which is used to switch between markup and code). In this case it was @Url.Action. My workaround was to move the method containing the @Url.Action to the bottom of the script block and I was then able to type freely above it without any duplicate characters.

e.g. With @Url.Action above my code:
[image: Duplicate characters appearing in]

With @Url.Action below my code:
[image]

Comment: This was definitely my case, and [Microsoft does not seem to care about it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/double-characters-when-typing-html-tags-in-cshtml/1637052), even if [it is happening at least since VS 2019](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-16103-editor-double-typing/1464938).

Comment: yes this is happening to me too im using vs 2022 thanks for the tip

Answer (score 9):

This was solved with the release of Visual Studio 2023 17.6.4

See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Duplicate-key-strokes-when-editing-scrip/10372422#T-N10396538

Comment: You meant Visual Studio 2022 right?

Answer (score 2):

Steps

1. Go to the project root folder
2. Delete contents of the `bin` and `obj` folders
3. Build the solution to regenerate the contents in the `bin` and `obj` folders
4. Check if your issue is resolved

[image: project root folder image for reference]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in .aspx files and the reason was similar to Paul H's answer. In my case <%...%> caused the issue:

```
function myFunction() {
    var variable = <%=(int)Session["Something"]%>;          
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hellos
    halllloo
    hhaalloo
    hhaalloo
    hhaalloo
    hhaalloo
    hhaalloo
    hhaalloo
    hhaalloo
}
```

With moving the <%...%> code to the bottom, solved my problem as well as a workaround:

```
function myFunction() {
    var variable = getSomething();
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
}

[...code...]

function getSomething() {
    var variable = <%=(int)Session["Something"]%>;
    return variable; 
}
```

Comment: Like mentioned in this [github thread](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/14206#discussioncomment-6189037) [Microsoft is working on that issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Duplicate-key-strokes-when-editing-javas/10372422).

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue today, things I tried which didn't work.

- Restarted Visual Studio
- Restarted PC
- Repaired Visual studio as above is mentioned.

The thing that worked was:

- To just close the opened file in visual studio and re-open the file.

I think, deleting the `.vs` folder in the project directory would also help it as it would close the opened documents when you restart it.